# Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.TileSource tile loaded event

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to post process an MapTile after it's been downloaded with via GetURI?

I'd like to apply some image processing to the maptiles after they've been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should look to do the image processing on the server where there's more resources.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. And it's not always more efficient to have your server do image processing. WP7 has built in support for a few pixel shaders, and if the gpx chip isn't working that hard, why not off load the work to it?